# Xcode: Reset CoreData after removeItemAtPath

Tags: swift, core-data

This may not be the best way to do it but it works sort of.

The schema of new version of my app is so different that I do not think it is reasonable to use migration. So I have decided to create an error screen that informs the user that they will lose their data. This works and the data gets removed but I have to relaunch the app to see the empty database. What would be the best way of doing this without relaunching the app?

Here is the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBAction func doneAction(sender: UIButton) {
    createAppData()
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NCStartMenuTV")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,
        .UserDomainMask, true)

    let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
    let newDir = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("CREWData.sqlite")

    do {
        try filemgr.removeItemAtPath(newDir)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        error.description 
    }
 }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    myTextView.text = "Your app will lose data if you proceed. Please accept our apologies but the new features in this version makes this necessary."
}
```

Working code to delete data and create new data.

---

```
@IBAction func doneAction(sender: UIButton) {

    deleteAppData ()

    createAppData()

    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NCStartMenuTV")
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 }

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    myTextView.text = "Your app will lose data if you proceed. Please accept our apologies but the new features in this version makes this necessary."
}
```

Comment: The app is still doing the same job for users though? So how much has the schema changed? If you don't tell users about this before the update is released be prepared for a *lot* of unhappy people...

Comment: I totally understand but as far as I can determine there aren't that many users since we haven't promoted the app. The keys of the entities changed.  I really think of the app as a Beta version. As you can probably guess I'm an amateur trying to develop an app for a small community. I also added a function to email all of the data as a backup. I'll look into  mapping the old keys to the new keys and save the data. I'll post the revised code for deleting the data above.

Answer (score 0):

> So I have decided to create an error screen that informs the user that they will lose their data.

Um. Wow. Your poor users. Please reconsider. Losing user data is one of the worst things an app can do. Trashing user data on purpose makes it even worse.

> What would be the best way of doing this without relaunching the app?

Remove the old data before doing anything with Core Data. Then you won't have any reason to relaunch.

```
let newDir = docsDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("CREWData.sqlite")

do {
    try filemgr.removeItemAtPath(newDir)
}
```

This code is pretty much guaranteed to fail. Core Data uses separate journal files, with the same name as the main persistent store but with `-wal` and `-shm` added. If you don't remove those, your data may well come back from the dead.

Comment: The data base changed so much that it would be impossible to migrate the data. I want to let the users know that rather than have the app crash. ... but I am not sure what you mean about remove old data before doing anything with core data? Do you mean to delete the data from entities? BTW I provided a function to let them eMail the data to themselves so it won't be too painful.

Comment: Your code snippet removes the old persistent store file. Do that before running any code that attempts to load data from the file.

Comment: I need to determine whether the data is old and the only way I can do this is by loading data and examining the content.  Can you suggest a better way?

Comment: I would still do it this way. Mark the new persistent store as "new" using a metadata value (`NSPersistentStore` has methods for reading and setting metadata on the persistent store file). Check for that value to decide if the data is "new" before loading it. The old persistent store won't have the value, but the new one will.